# Is it possible to decide which function runs on which processor in MPI or any other c++ library?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, parallel-processing, mpi

Suppose I had 8 processes and four processors/cores.Can I allocate specific processes to specific cores before program execution?

e.g

Processor 1= process no 4,5
Processor 2= process no 1,3
Processor 3= process no 2,6
Processor 4= process no 7,8

Comment: Even if you could modify the affinity by hand, don't do that. Let the scheduler do its job. Its better than you for that. I remember an Atwood's article about that: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/thread-priorities-are-evil.html

Comment: Manu343726, that's not necessarily true.  For example, see Hager, et al. "Communication characteristics and hybrid MPI/OpenMP parallel programming on clusters of multi-core SMP nodes" page 9, where an inter-socket communication pattern can perform 20-40% worse than intra-socket.  SGI provides utilities like omplace (http://www.nas.nasa.gov/hecc/support/kb/Using-SGI-omplace-for-Pinning_287.html) to deal with these situations.  It might be premature optimization, but not necessarily.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at the [SetProcessorAffinityMask()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. It's not exactly what you want, but the closest you can get, IMHO.

> *A process affinity mask is a bit vector in which each bit represents a logical processor on which the threads of the process are allowed to run. The value of the process affinity mask must be a subset of the system affinity mask values obtained by the GetProcessAffinityMask function. A process is only allowed to run on the processors configured into a system. Therefore, the process affinity mask cannot specify a 1 bit for a processor when the system affinity mask specifies a 0 bit for that processor.*

I'd recommend to also look at the comments on that page.

Answer (score 0):

What operating system? See [sched_setaffinity cpu affinity in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392656/sched-setaffinity-cpu-affinity-in-linux) for Linux.

Comment: Windows 7 and using visual studio.

Comment: That's not an answer, that's a comment to ask for details.